# Clustering Variable

Tags: logistic, clustering

I have a set of 10 variables (v1..v10) which are continuous. I have another two control variables ctrl11 and ctrl12 which of course are categorical. ctrl11 can take any values from 1 to 50 and ctrl12 can take any value from 1 to 200.

I am trying to shrink ctrl11 and ctrl12 to about 5-10 categories rather than the current 50 and 200 respectively. The end goal is to use the shrunk version of one of these two in a logit regression along with v1..v10, ie a total of 11 DVs. So my idea is to see how the variables v1..v10 cluster.

Is this strategy sensible?

How can I find which control variable they cluster along so that I shrink that variable and discard the other for use in the regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, there is no "of course" that control variables have to be categorical. Control variables can take any form - dichotomous, categorical, ordinal, continuous....

Next, your general goal of collapsing some categories is almost certainly worthwhile - even if your N is large enough to include all those levels, it will be hard to evaluate a model with all of them included. But then your final sentences seem to switch the goal to using only one of the two variables - that seems unnecessary; it is certainly reasonable to have more than one control variable (provided they aren't colinear and that you have large enough N).

It would really help to know what these variables *are*. But, generally, I would collapse categories based on substantive knowledge, not statistical considerations. For example, if one control variable was "state" (as in which of the United States) I might collapse into region. I would also look at the frequencies of each category - categories with small frequencies would be higher on my priority list for combining. Sometimes, a few categories have to be combined into an "other" category.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I am not able to upvote your answer but I accept it. As you guessed, one of the control variables is state. The other is the industry.